# What is best antonym for 'prior'?

Tags: antonyms

For example, you could say

> Event 1 must occur prior to event 2.

But what word could be used to say

> Event 2 must occur [?] to event 1?

Can the word 'prior' be directly replaced? Or does the sentence only work if, for example, 'to' is taken from the sentence?

Comment: I can't see what your question has to do with _tense_. It seems you are looking for the antonym (opposite) of _prior_.

Comment: I edited your question to reflect what _I think_ you want to ask. _Prior_ is not any tense, past, present or future. If I'm mistaken, and you disagree with the edit, feel free to revert it!

Comment: "E2 must occur __after__ E1". Did you check a thesaurus for alternatives?

Comment: @Mitch I was wondering if you could keep the word 'to'; oerkelens answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: @oerkelens Yes, the antonym is what I was looking for. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: "E2 must occur __posterior to__ E1". Did a thesaurus say anything else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be looking for an *antonym* of *prior*.

> Event 1 must occur prior to event 2.

Would mean the same as

> Event 2 must happen *[subsequent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/subsequent)* to event 1.

Comment: Yes. And depending on context: *following* or *after* also work (without "*to*"). Likewise, *next event*.